# Hide Border Bottom on PieChart from Highchart

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have 2 partial views, and each holds their own Pie Chart (made from Highcharts).  I load these partials in my main view by calling the *Action* in the corresponding *Controller*.

Now I found out how to get rid of the credits at the bottom of the chart, but when I load the two pie charts in my view I get [image: this]

As you can see, there is a faint gray line going across the bottom of these charts.

Now in my HTML on my main view where I call these partial views.. I use `col-md-6` on both of them to get them to line up next to each other, like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.Action("Chart", "Teams")
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.Action("SeriesWinsChart", "Teams")
</div>
```

I have gone into the DOM explorer to try and find what is causing that border-bottom and I can't seem to find it. I also have tried giving the `col-md-6` a property of `border-bottom: none;` but that did not work.

Here is what I see when I am on the page and click 'view source' for that section:

```
<div id='chart2_container'></div><script type='text/javascript'>
var chart2;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: { renderTo:'chart2_container', plotShadow: false }, 
        credits: { enabled: false }, 
        plotOptions: { pie: { allowPointSelect: true, cursor: 'pointer', dataLabels: { color: '#000000', connectorColor: '#000000', formatter: function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y; } } } }, 
        title: { style: { font: 'normal 20px Impact', color: 'red' }, text: 'Game Wins' }, 
        series: [{ data: [['Orioles', 5], ['Red Sox', 10]], name: 'Game Wins', type: 'pie' }]
    });
});
</script>

<hr />

</div>
```

I am going to assume that the `<hr/>` is what is causing this, so how I do I get rid of that in JS?

How do I get rid of the border-bottom?

Comment: Might not be a border-bottom.  Could be a gray background behind your two divs.  Could be a box-shadow. Might be a border-top on an element below the charts.  Could be a number of issues.  You'll need to provide more info.  What if you swap the charts out with some text.  Does the line still show up?

Comment: @JesseLee just commented out the charts.. and swapped for text and there aren't any borders when I do that.. I am going to edit my question to show what I see when I 'view source' on the page

Comment: Border has nothing to do with charts. Remove `<hr />` from HTML. If you really need to remove it using JS then you could use jQuery - $('#chart2_container ~ hr').remove();

Comment: @KacperMadej I am unable to remove the `<hr />` from HTML because I only see that when I 'view source' on the actual page.. not in Visual Studio where my HTML  is... so I tried `$('#chart2_container').remove();` on the top of my Index.cshtml page and that did not work either.

Comment: You could find where is this `<hr />` coming from and fix source of the issue. Other way could be to remove hr element in chart's callback function, but first option is better.